# Create NSAttributedString from RTF Text File in iOS 6

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios6, nsattributedstring

I need to create an `NSAttributedString` from an `.rtf` text file, so that it maintains the text attributes. In iOS 7, I use this code:

```
NSError *error;
NSURL *stringURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"Text" withExtension:@".rtf"];
NSAttributedString *myAttributedText = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithFileURL:stringURL options:nil documentAttributes:nil error:&error];
```

However, `initWithFileURL:options:documentAttributes:error:` is only available in iOS 7.0

What can I use for iOS 6?